# Smoothing of Log Data Plots in Octave

Tags: octave, averaging

I have some frequency based data that I'm plotting with Octave's semilogx that looks like this:

[image: noisy data semilogx plot]

The amplitude of peaks does not increase with frequency over the linear scale. But with a log scale, data density increases and makes the data appear larger at high frequencies.

Is there a method of smoothing, like you might do with sgolayfilt, where low frequencies are filtered less than high frequencies so as to compensate for the higher frequency data being more dense due to the log x scale?